# Java link two variables?

Tags: java, variables

Looking for a away to link two variables. sort of like a hashmap but where the key acts as a value and a key. for example, i want to keep track of two people having a conversation.

```
    int recipient1ID = 1111;
    int recipient2ID = 2222; 

    LinkedVar<Integer, Integer> conversation = new LinkedVar<Integer, Integer>();

    conversation.put(recipient1ID, recipient2ID);// add link

    conversation.get(recipient1ID);// returns recipient2ID
    conversation.get(recipient2ID);// returns recipient1ID
```

i want to call one variable and it return the other. i hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want a bimap... e.g. https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be implemented using two `Map`s, one for each relation direction.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> caller2recipient = ...;
Map<Integer, Integer> recipient2caller = ...;
```

Aggregating these two maps you could implement your `LinkedVar` class as:

```
public class LinkedVar<T> {

    public LinkedVar() {
        fromto = new HashMap<T,T>();
        tofrom = new HashMap<T,T>();
    }

    public boolean put(T a, T b)
    {
        if(fromto.containsKey(a) || tofrom.containsKey(b))
            return false;
        fromto.put(a, b);
        tofrom.put(b, a);
        return true;
    }

    public T get(T key)   
    {
        for(Map<T,T> m: Arrays.asList(fromto, tofrom))
            if(m.containsKey(key)) return m.get(key);
        return null;
    }

    private Map<T,T> fromto;
    private Map<T,T> tofrom;

}
```

Below, this class used in your example:

```
    int recipient1ID = 1111;
    int recipient2ID = 2222; 

    LinkedVar<Integer> conversation = new LinkedVar<>();
    conversation.put(recipient1ID, recipient2ID);// add link

    System.out.println(conversation.get(recipient1ID));// returns recipient2ID
    System.out.println(conversation.get(recipient2ID));// returns recipient1ID
```

Note that, as `BiMap` class from Guava library does, `LinkedVar` could be parametrized with two types (one for the key and one for the value) but that implies `get` has to be splitted into two methods with **different method identifiers**:

- get
- getReverse

If they were identified by the same name:

```
public S get(T key)   
{
    if(fromto.containsKey(key)) return fromto.get(key);
    return null;
}


public T get(S key)   
{
    if(tofrom.containsKey(key)) return tofrom.get(key);
    return null;
}
```

Java could not distinguish both methods for those cases where `T` and `S` are the same type.
In fact, Java's compiler (in contrast to G++) won't allow to deffine that template.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) - it's a bidirectional map that may fill your needs. The api looks a bit different though.